# What is the meaning of the diagram in All You Need Is Kill?

Tags: all-you-need-is-kill

This diagram appears at the beginning of *All You Need Is Kill* :

[image]

The diagram has no title or description, and it's not clear to me what the numbers and the overall diagram mean (I have the Kindle edition, so perhaps something was lost in the conversion). Are they unit numbers to show deployment in the battle? Are they hangar numbers or something similar showing the base layout? Neither seem to match the numbers used in the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note**: Before posting the question I did my due diligence and found the answer myself. I'm still posting this so that it will be a reference for anyone else (I wasn't the only one with the question: the [top Google hit](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/bbs/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=984518) for "all you need is kill diagram" has the same question but no answer).

---

I found a [blog post](http://sfpotpourri.blogspot.com/2014/08/2004-all-you-need-is-kill-sakurazaka.html) with an off-hand remark that it's a "plot sequence" diagram to "assist the reader in understanding the flow of events". I didn't think the flow of events was that difficult to understand...but the remark makes sense: the diagram shows the flow of time from top to bottom, and each number `x-y` refers to chapter `x`, section `y`.

The diagram matches the flow of events in the book: the earliest events are Rita's backstory in Chapter 3, then the introduction of Private Kiriya and the beginning of the time loops in Chapter 1, etc.